# Socket.io not working on node server

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, socket.io

I'm running a server and all it needs to do is connect to a 3rd party public socket.io stream. I have it working in my react app but can't get it to work on my server. I'm using node and express.When I run I get no errors. Here is my code

```js
var express = require("express");
var app = express();
var port = 3000;
var io = require('socket.io-client/dist/socket.io');


var socket = io.connect('http://socket.coincap.io', {transports: ['websocket']});

socket.on('trades', function(tradeMsg) {

console.log("worked");

});



app.listen(port, () => {
 console.log("Server listening on port " + port);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Just checked my code, I do something like the following which is a bit different than your code. Don't know if it's your solution but maybe that could helps you.

In a separate `socket-io.js`

```
module.exports = function (app, server) {
     var socketIO = require('socket.io').listen(server, {'transports': ['websocket']});
     global.socketIO = socketIO;

     socketIO.set('origins', '*:*');

     socketIO.sockets.on('trades', function (tradeMsg) {
         console.log("worked");
     });
 };
```

Then in my `www` after `var server = http.createServer(app);` I've got:

```
require('socket-io')(app, server);
```

Comment: Thank you. The thing is I'm only using the socket.io client as I just need to get information on my server.

Answer (score 0):

You can try installing `socket.io-client` using `npm`.

`npm install socket.io-client --save`

And try running the following code. It should work fine.

```
var express = require("express");
var app = express();
var port = 3000;

var socket = require('socket.io-client')('http://socket.coincap.io');


socket.on('trades', function(tradeMsg) {

    console.log("worked");

});



app.listen(port, () => {
   console.log("Server listening on port " + port);
});
```